# portrait orientation is ignored on Nexus 5X (SDK 7)

Tags: android, screen-orientation

All my Activity are in the portrait orientation and there is a strange behavior on **Nexus 5X**:

1. Mobile on landscape orientation
2. I click on my App to show a new Activity
3. This news Activity appears 1s in landscape mode, then automatically in portrait mode...

All Activity extend a base class with:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
     ...
```

I don't set anything in the manifest.

Have you got some explanations guys?

Comment: Is there some reason you're using `setRequestedOrientation()` inside `onCreate()` instead of the `android:screenOrientation` attr in your manifest?

Comment: No reason. Do you think it's better into manifest versus programmatically?

Comment: @anthony did you find any solution on this yet ? I'm facing the same issue on Nexus device. And per my requirement I don't want to set orientation in Manifest

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation for `Activity.setRequestedOrientation()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setRequestedOrientation(int)):

> If the activity is currently in the foreground or otherwise impacting the screen orientation, the screen will immediately be changed (possibly causing the activity to be restarted).

This means it's possible for your activity to start up in a different orientation, and then re-start in the orientation you requested.

If you use [the `android:screenOrientation` attribute](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#screen) instead, this will not happen.

Comment: I have the problem on Nexus 5X (Android 8.1)